# What are the main arguments by proponents of the American two party system?

Tags: united-states, parties, voting-systems

Q: What are the main arguments by proponents of the American two party system as opposed to a multi-party system in other federated countries like for example Germany?

Note: The answers in the question linked below, talk mostly about how the current system is preferential to a two party system, and not so much about the arguments for keeping it / against changing it.

[Advantages of two party system](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2350/what-are-the-advantages-of-a-two-party-system-vs-multiple-party-system)

Comment: This is going to boil down to a bunch of opinions.  BC, Canada had a recent referendum (not the first, I'd add) that proposed a move away from first-past-the-post voting.  The reformers, for multi-party systems, very vocal about being in the right, were waaay ahead on social media.  Actual turnout was 60%+ in favor of leaving things as they are.  I can give examples of bad multiparty systems, but I'm sure someone else can point to examples justifying multi-party systems.  Answers will be opinion-based.  Welcome aboard, don't mean to disrespect, only... this is unlikely to have clear answers.

Comment: As you have read the answers you link, you should have understood that there is no argument to keep the two parties, but there are arguments to keep the current system (that leads to having only 2 parties)

Comment: @MartinSchröder that's exactly the thread I linked in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The strongest argument can be put different ways, but it is really just one:

Fear of change / Never change a running system / The inability to absolutely guarantee the new system will quickly settle into a balanced and stable multi party system.

After that, what makes things complicated is that there isn't simply "the multi-party system" and "the two-party system" - once you start talking about a specific system, the arguments will get more specific and be aimed at the weak points of that specific system.

For example, first past the post's 1 rep per district system has very good local resolution - you get 1 rep, presumably living in your presumably small district, that you get to vote on. Some multi-party systems (e.g. Germany's) address this, others don't.